# OpenCV Python Stitching: Define custom keypoints / matches skipping feature detector & matcher

Tags: python, opencv, keypoint, opencv-stitching

I'm trying to implement the panorama stitching via OpenCV into our process, but want to use control points / matches gathered from PTGui.

PTGui however just lists the keypoints and the matches between images, no angles or additional data.

When using the normal workflow, the feature set is a list of [ImageFeatures](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/db5/structcv_1_1detail_1_1ImageFeatures.html) containing some parameters and a list of [Keypoints](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html).

Since I'm using OpenCV in Python, I don't really know how to create the list of ImageFeatures from scratch.

This is the current implementation, which doesn't work:

```
f1 = cv.detail_ImageFeatures()
f1.img_idx = 0
f1.descriptors = None
f1.img_size = (1920, 1080)
f1.keypoints = (
    cv.KeyPoint(1412.0, 734.0, 5.0),
    cv.KeyPoint(1415.0, 856.0, 5.0),
    cv.KeyPoint(1398.0, 885.0, 5.0)
)

...

features = [f1, f2, ...]
```

I get the following error when using my custom list just on the next step, which would be the matching: `cv2.error: Conversion error: features`

In addition to the custom ImageFeatures, I would also need custom matches. According to the documentation, these should be a [MatchesInfo](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d9a/structcv_1_1detail_1_1MatchesInfo.html) struct containing matches of type [DMatch](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/de0/classcv_1_1DMatch.html).

These are currently implemented as follows, but can't be tested since the above error already occurs beforehand:

```
matches = (
  cv.detail_MatchesInfo(confidence=1.0, dst_img_idx=1, H=None, inliers_mask=None, matches=(
    cv.DMatch(0, 0, 0.0),
    cv.DMatch(1, 1, 0.0),
    cv.DMatch(2, 2, 0.0)), num_inliers=None, src_img_idx=0),
  ...
)
```

So I was wondering, if it is even possible to "import" custom control points and matches using OpenCV Python. If yes, what would have to be changed to make it work.

Comment: What is the code leading to the error message? I can't seem to find that line.

Comment: It's basically any function after the feature detection in the stitching pipeline. In the case above it would be `cv.detail_BestOf2NearestMatcher(**kwargs).apply2(features, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: I want to add custom keypoint stitching as Feature in my [stitching](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching) package anyway. Why dont you open an issue with sample Images and keypoints?

Comment: @LukasWeber I was using your package for testing, but my question above was just for a generic sample.

I tested the implementation in C++ and it worked, but another issue came up:
In most cases, I have 2 fisheye cameras both taking 180° images, which don't have any overlapping keypoints. Using PTGui, these images can be aligned easily, but the export only gives me a yaw, pitch and roll per image and a general focal length, so I don't really know how to convert these to OpenCV `CameraParams`.